# How can I give a background for an object on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I made a little canvas and create a square with path drawing moveto() and lineto() orders.

So I have a square with red borders and I can give a background color with fillStyle and it gets the color with fill().

It executes by click.

```
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
c.id = 'myCanvas';
c.style.background = "#ffffff";
c.width = "100";
c.height = "50";
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(c);

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(0, 80);
ctx.lineTo(50, 80);
ctx.lineTo(50, 0);
ctx.lineTo(0, 0);   
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.stroke();

var getColor2 = 0;
var getColor = 0;

c.addEventListener("click", function(){
       if(getColor2 == 0){
          ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
       }
       if(getColor2 == 1){
          ctx.fillStyle = "#ff33df";
       }
       if(getColor2 == 2){
          ctx.fillStyle = "#bbbbbb";
       }
       if(getColor2 == 3){
          ctx.fillStyle = "#bb4563";
       }
       if(getColor2 == 4){
          ctx.fillStyle = "#234556";
          getColor2 = -1; 
       }

       getColor2++;
       ctx.fill();

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mafb7qhh/2/

My problem is: it executes when I click on the canvas as well.
I would like to execute by clicking on the square only.

Comment: You have to calculate by yourself if you clicked on the square using its position/size and cursor position because the square does not exist

Comment: Oh I see. That's not an object just a rounded area. What's happening if I have more squares?

Comment: everything you draw inside a canvas can't be "selected" , if you need some clickable areas maybe the SVG can come in handy instead of canvas, or else using an invisible dom element over the canvas with the same position/size of the element you drew

Comment: Another way is you can watch the mouse click event over the canvas, and get the mouse x and y values then cycle through your objects to see if it falls within it. Note that you may have to sort objects if they overlap to determine which one is clicked (top most). (Also, enhance it by adding mouse over, and changing the border color of the square!)

Comment: I made this little jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qwcb7p7o/1/ , checking from a list of rectangles if the mouse is over or not as example if you whish to handle mouse events using canvas (only for rectangles).

Comment: @Saba. Your fiddle solves the question. You should post it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you draw inside a canvas can't be "selected" because it does not exist like a DOM Element.
If you need some clickable areas maybe the `SVG` can come in handy instead of canvas, or else using an invisible dom element over the canvas with the same position/size of the element you drew

Anyway, I made this little [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwcb7p7o/1/) , checking from a list of rectangles if the mouse is over or not as example if you whish to handle mouse events using canvas (only for rectangles).

For more complex polygons you have to use (for example) a `ray casting algorithm`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon